# Tkinter : changing window screen in same window , I am new to stack overflow , ignore spelling mistakes 

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a login.py page using tkinter and I have created a connect database.py page also ,so my doubt is i have a button called login in connect database window , now the how to give argument such as if I click the login button the screen shd change to my login.py screen .....hope u understand my doubtt

PS : this is my first ques in stack overflow

Comment: please show us the code you tried and maybe occuring errors

Comment: Yeaa okk I will

Answer (score 0):

***You should use multimodule system in python and import your module with your login window.***

```
from login.py import logginWindowFunction
```

**So you can use given functions from this file, for example:**

```
Button['command'] = logginWindowFunction
```

**Also you can import whole file:**

```
import login.py as lg
Button['command'] = lg.logginWindowFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

tkinter buttons has `command` keyword argument to add a functionality to your button , more info : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.html
just add whatever function that change to the other screen when you login